# Moving averages with multiple GroupBy

Tags: r, group-by, subset, dplyr, moving-average

This is a small rep of my data:

```
Team <- rep(c("ind", "sas", "ind", "sas"),c(4,8,2,4))

Player <- c("Paul George", "David West", "Roy Hibbert",
            "Paul George", "Tim Duncan", "Manuel Ginobili",
            "Tony Parker", "Boris Diaw","Danny Green", 
            "Kawhi Leonard", "Matt Bonner", "Patty Mills",
            "George Hill", "C.J.Miles","Tim Duncan",
            "Manuel Ginobili", "Tony Parker", "Boris Diaw")

Team_PTS <- c(101,101,101,98,105,105,105,105,
              105,105,105,105,98,98,89,89,89,128)

Date <- as.Date(c("2015-05-14", "2015-05-14", "2015-05-14",
               "2015-05-16","2015-05-15", "2015-05-15", "2015-05-15",
               "2015-05-15","2015-05-15", "2015-05-15", "2015-05-15",
               "2015-05-15","2015-05-16","2015-05-16","2015-05-29",
               "2015-05-29","2015-05-29","2015-06-03"))

Team_Gamenumber <- rep(c(1,2,1,2,2,3),c(3,1,8,2,3,1))

df <- data.frame(Team,Player,Team_PTS,Date, Team_Gamenumber)

df

   Team          Player Team_PTS       Date Team_Gamenumber Desired_output
1   ind     Paul George      101 2015-05-14               1            101
2   ind      David West      101 2015-05-14               1            101
3   ind     Roy Hibbert      101 2015-05-14               1            101
4   ind     Paul George       98 2015-05-16               2           99.5
5   sas      Tim Duncan      105 2015-05-15               1            105
6   sas Manuel Ginobili      105 2015-05-15               1            105
7   sas     Tony Parker      105 2015-05-15               1            105
8   sas      Boris Diaw      105 2015-05-15               1            105
9   sas     Danny Green      105 2015-05-15               1            105
10  sas   Kawhi Leonard      105 2015-05-15               1            105
11  sas     Matt Bonner      105 2015-05-15               1            105
12  sas     Patty Mills      105 2015-05-15               1            105
13  ind     George Hill       98 2015-05-16               2           99.5
14  ind       C.J.Miles       98 2015-05-16               2           99.5
15  sas      Tim Duncan       89 2015-05-29               2             97
16  sas Manuel Ginobili       89 2015-05-29               2             97
17  sas     Tony Parker       89 2015-05-29               2             97
18  sas      Boris Diaw      128 2015-06-03               3         107.33
```

The desired output variable is the moving or cummulative average of the Team points (sas and ind in this example).

I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Team) %>%
       mutate(cumavg_PTS = cumsum(Team_PTS) / seq_along(Team_PTS))
```

However that yields a wrong output since the information is organized by players. See Boris Diaw misses game 2 with sas but plays on game 3.

Also I think `cumsum` is not the right approach in this case because the average will be affected by the number of players that play every single match.

The 107.33 comes from the average of sas first 3 games (105 + 89 + 128)/3

Comment: it is not clear to me how do you want to group the elements. First grouping by `Team` and then?

Comment: @SabDem you group by Team but the information is organized by players (there are multiple players playing each game) so that is what is difficulting my calculation of the moving average. See for ind once paul george plays the 2nd game then the average moves from 101 to 99.5 because ind score 101 and 98 pts in first and second game

Comment: `require(forecast); ?forecast::ma`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your `Team_PTS` column is redundant, in that it contains the number of points scored by the entire `Team` in game `Team_Gamenumber`, however the data.frame contains one row per *player* per game (that that player played in). Thus every record for that `Team` and `Team_Gamenumber` has the same `Team_PTS` value.

You can therefore "aggregate" the original `df` on `Team` and `Team_Gamenumber`, taking the first element of the redundant `Team_PTS` vector for the group, since all values in the group are the same anyway. As part of this `aggregate()` call I also solved the issue that you stored the `Team_PTS` values as strings, which were turned into factors by the `data.frame()` call. The easiest way I am aware that this can be done is by coercing from factor to actual character strings and then to numeric.

The aggregated table can then by supplemented with the `Desired_Output` column by grouping by `Team` and then using the `cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)` formula. This result can then be merged back with `df` to produce the desired result.

Also note that I manually reordered `output` to correspond with your expected output, just so we can verify easily by eye that it matches.

```
df <- data.frame(Team=rep(c('ind','sas','ind','sas'),c(4,8,2,4)),Player=c('Paul George','David West','Roy Hibbert','Paul George','Tim Duncan','Manuel Ginobili','Tony Parker','Boris Diaw','Danny Green','Kawhi Leonard','Matt Bonner','Patty Mills','George Hill','C.J.Miles','Tim Duncan','Manuel Ginobili','Tony Parker','Boris Diaw'),Team_PTS=c(101,101,101,98,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,98,98,89,89,89,128),Date=as.Date(c('2015-05-14','2015-05-14','2015-05-14','2015-05-16','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-15','2015-05-16','2015-05-16','2015-05-29','2015-05-29','2015-05-29','2015-06-03')),Team_Gamenumber=rep(c(1,2,1,2,2,3),c(3,1,8,2,3,1)));
output <- merge(df,transform(aggregate(cbind(Team_PTS=as.double(as.character(Team_PTS)))~Team+Team_Gamenumber,df,`[`,1),Desired_Output=ave(Team_PTS,Team,FUN=function(x) cumsum(x)/seq_along(x))))[,c(names(df),'Desired_Output')];
output[c(1:4,9,10,7,8,13,14,11,12,5,6,16:18,15),];
##    Team          Player Team_PTS       Date Team_Gamenumber Desired_Output
## 1   ind     Paul George      101 2015-05-14               1       101.0000
## 2   ind      David West      101 2015-05-14               1       101.0000
## 3   ind     Roy Hibbert      101 2015-05-14               1       101.0000
## 4   ind     Paul George       98 2015-05-16               2        99.5000
## 9   sas      Tim Duncan      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 10  sas Manuel Ginobili      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 7   sas     Tony Parker      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 8   sas      Boris Diaw      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 13  sas     Danny Green      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 14  sas   Kawhi Leonard      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 11  sas     Matt Bonner      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 12  sas     Patty Mills      105 2015-05-15               1       105.0000
## 5   ind     George Hill       98 2015-05-16               2        99.5000
## 6   ind       C.J.Miles       98 2015-05-16               2        99.5000
## 16  sas      Tim Duncan       89 2015-05-29               2        97.0000
## 17  sas Manuel Ginobili       89 2015-05-29               2        97.0000
## 18  sas     Tony Parker       89 2015-05-29               2        97.0000
## 15  sas      Boris Diaw      128 2015-06-03               3       107.3333
```

Comment: many thanks! is it necessary to rearrange columns to calculate output?

Comment: That's a side effect of the `merge()` call; it always places the "merge-by" columns first. If you want to preserve the original column order, you can add an index operation onto the end of the massive one-liner (thus making it more massive) as follows: `output <- ...[,c(names(df),'Desired_Output')]`.

Comment: @Sburg13 I just edited my answer to include the column order preservation index operation.

Comment: thanks! works well!! the issue of team_PTS stored as strings doesn't need to be solved since in my real data that is not an issue and I created the issue when posting the example

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way. I'll do it using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cavg := { dups = !duplicated(Team_Gamenumber)
                      cumsum(Team_PTS * dups) / cumsum(dups)
                    }, by = Team]
```

Or just write a function:

```
foo <- function(points, game) {
    dups = !duplicated(game)
    cumsum(points * dups) / cumsum(dups)
}
setDT(df)[, cavg := foo(Team_PTS, Team_Gamenumber), by = Team]
```

---

There's still a difference between the solutions of @bgoldst and @jeremycg. @bgoldst's computes the cumulative averages on the data sorted by `Team, Team_Gamenumber`, where as @jeremycg's computes by preserving the original order.

For example, from your `df`, interchange the game number for `ind = 1`:

```
setDT(df)[c(1:4,13:14), Team_Gamenumber := c(2,2,2,1,1,1)]
setDF(df)
```

Then try both the versions.

---

We can get both answers while preserving the original order of the data as follows:

```
# @jeremycg's
setDT(df)[, cavg := foo(Team_PTS, Team_Gamenumber), by = Team]
# @bglodst's
setDT(df)[order(Team, Team_Gamenumber), cavg := foo(Team_PTS, Team_Gamenumber), by = Team]
```

Answer (score 3):

using `dplyr`, in a horrible mess:

```
df %>% distinct(Team, Team_Gamenumber) %>%
       group_by(Team) %>%
       mutate(cumavg_PTS = cummean(Team_PTS)) %>%
       select(Team, Team_Gamenumber, cumavg_PTS) %>%
       inner_join(df, .)

Joining by: c("Team", "Team_Gamenumber")
   Team          Player Team_PTS       Date Team_Gamenumber cumavg_PTS
1   ind     Paul George      101 2015-05-14               1   101.0000
2   ind      David West      101 2015-05-14               1   101.0000
3   ind     Roy Hibbert      101 2015-05-14               1   101.0000
4   ind     Paul George       98 2015-05-16               2    99.5000
5   sas      Tim Duncan      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
6   sas Manuel Ginobili      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
7   sas     Tony Parker      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
8   sas      Boris Diaw      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
9   sas     Danny Green      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
10  sas   Kawhi Leonard      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
11  sas     Matt Bonner      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
12  sas     Patty Mills      105 2015-05-15               1   105.0000
13  ind     George Hill       98 2015-05-16               2    99.5000
14  ind       C.J.Miles       98 2015-05-16               2    99.5000
15  sas      Tim Duncan       89 2015-05-29               2    97.0000
16  sas Manuel Ginobili       89 2015-05-29               2    97.0000
17  sas     Tony Parker       89 2015-05-29               2    97.0000
18  sas      Boris Diaw      128 2015-06-03               3   107.3333
```

Comment: Your solution works perfect with the example but it shows some issues with the real data. I have been checking your formula and I understand all you do until the inner_join part. Could you explain how that works? thank you again

Comment: see  ?inner_join - it merges the original df with the modified one based on Team and Team_Gamenumber. What is it doing wrong? You might need to add `arrange(Team, Team_Gamenumber)` if your data isn't in order

Comment: but the example data is not in order either... will keep trying and let you know if works. thanks

Comment: you could also replace inner_join by merge(df, .) and it will give the same answer if that helps